# Using Dialog callback results in error when clearing an array

Tags: angular, xcode, cordova

Using Angular 6, I am using Cordova's dialog callback to reset / clear an array when the "Reset" button is pressed.

Here is the code:

```
selections:any[] = [];

resetSelections(){
  if (this.selections.length) {
    navigator['notification'].confirm(
        "Would you like to reset your selections for this group?",
        this.onConfirm,
        "", //Blank Title
        ['Cancel','Reset']
        )
  }
}

onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
  if (buttonIndex == "2") {
    console.log("You pressed Reset!");
    this.selections = [];
  }
}
```

When "Reset" is clicked on the device, the Xcodeconsole logs "You pressed Reset!" but does not clear the array and results in the following error:

> Error in Success callbackId: Notification407093698 : TypeError: null
>   is not an object (evaluating 'this.selections=[]')

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got this to work. However, I used a workaround that involved creating a Bootstrap modal with a button that clears the array correctly now.